# But could I have just plugged in $20\unicode{xB0}$ to find the exact value of $\sin(10\unicode{xB0})$? (Addendum my previous question)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

---

---

$$2\text{ days ago}$$

---

---

$2$ days ago, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4710117/math-for-fun-finding-the-exact-value-of-sin10-unicodexb0) question asking about how to find the exact value of $\sin(\def\a#1{#1\unicode{xB0}}\a{10})$, which was surprisingly well received question for me. In this question, I used the knowledge of $\sin\left(\a{\dfrac x2}\right)$ being equal to $\pm\sqrt{\dfrac12(1-\cos(x))}$ to generate a formula to determine a formula to get the exact value of $\sin\left(\a{\dfrac x3}\right)$, however, I am wondering now if I could have just plugged in $2\a0$ for $x$ in the formula to determine the exact value of $\sin\left(\a{\dfrac x2}\right)$ to get the exact value of $\sin(1\a0)$. Here is my reasoning:

---

---

$$\sin(1\a0)=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac12(1-\cos(20))}$$$$=\pm\sqrt{0.5-\dfrac{\cos\left(\dfrac\pi9\right)}2}$$$$=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos\left(\dfrac\pi9\right)}2}$$Which, if we wanted to simplify this even further, we would get$$\pm\dfrac12\cdot\sqrt2\sqrt{1-\cos\left(\dfrac\pi9\right)}$$Setting this equal to the answer posted by [@Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel):$$\pm\dfrac12\cdot\sqrt2\sqrt{1-\cos\left(\dfrac\pi9\right)}=\frac{\omega - \overline{\omega}}{2i} = -\frac{i}{2} \left( \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2}\right)^{1/3} - \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}\right)^{1/3}\right)$$And when we plug this into Wolfram Alpha, it turns out that the two equations are only equal to each other when $\sin(2\a0)$ is positive:

[image]

And when $\sin(2\a0)$ is negative:

[image]

---

#### Imgur links for reference if they are not loading:

[Test for when the sine of x over 2 yields a positive result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecODZ.png)

[Test for when the sine of x over 2 yields a negative result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fytVE.png)

---

### My question

---

---

Why is it, that when we achieve the solution for the exact solution for $\sin(1\a0)$ using the formula for finding the exact value of $\sin\left(\a{\dfrac x2}\right)$, it is only equal to the exact value of $\sin(1\a0)$ that the answer to my last question received only when the formula for $\sin\left(\a{\dfrac x2}\right)$ provides a positive result?

---

---

### To clarify

---

---

Note: If my title seems a bit long, you may edit it. However, and I know this may not be a valid point, I just feel like it is important to mention that this is an addendum to my previous question so it doesn't get marked as a duplicate of my previous question. It also might seem a bit long in the sense that it is a total of $134$ characters long at the time of posting this question. Feel free to edit this post in any way if you think that that part of the question might need to be edited for any reason. However, if you do decide to edit this, please be careful to not edit any defined functions, as that might break the entire post.

Comment: $\sin{20º}$ cannot be negative. Have a look at unit circle and what values of $\sin$ are positive and negative. Go by quadrants. Which quadrant does angle $20º$ land in? Is $\sin$ positive there? The half-angle formula for $\sin$ that you stated encloses all quadrants, hence positives apply to certain angles and  negatives to other. See [Unit Circle](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/unit-circle.html).